# Template functions in C++ for immutable arrays

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a template function that will return true if a value from an immutable array exists, and false otherwise. Here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>

using std::find;

#include <vector>

using std::vector;

template<class T>
bool contains(const T *arr, int size, T val) {
    vector<T> dest(arr, arr + size);

    T *p = find(dest.begin(), dest.end(), val);

    if (p == arr + size)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Every time I compile against a simple test program I get these errors:

```
main.cpp:10:   instantiated from 'void testit(const T*, int, T) [with T = char]'
main.cpp:37:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:69: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >' to 'char*' in initialization
main.cpp: In function 'bool contains(const T*, int, T) [with T = int]':
main.cpp:10:   instantiated from 'void testit(const T*, int, T) [with T = int]'
main.cpp:43:   instantiated from here
main.cpp:69: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' to 'int*' in initialization
main.cpp: In function 'bool contains(const T*, int, T) [with T = std::string]':
main.cpp:10:   instantiated from 'void testit(const T*, int, T) [with T = std::string]'
main.cpp:44:   instantiated from here
```

(All of those errors are on the line that contains the `find` function)

What is the best way to go about this? Is the vector even neccessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the vector even neccessary?

No.

```
template<class T>
bool contains(const T *arr, int size, T val) {
    return std::find(arr, arr + size, val) != arr + size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the argument is not an actual, complete array T.C.'s answer's solid (though taking the value by reference is a good idea), but if you only want to support entire arrays you can have something a smidge easier to use, with the array size extracted from the array's type:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
inline bool contains(const T(&arr)[N], const T& val)
{
    return std::find(arr, arr + N, val) != arr + N;
}
```

Of course you can have both versions overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

> error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >' to 'char*' in initialization

This is telling you the return type you have is not correct for `std::find`.

*For the code you have*, you should have something like the following.

```
template<class T>
bool contains(const T *arr, int size, T val)
{
    vector<T> dest(arr, arr + size);

    vector<T>::iterator p = find(dest.begin(), dest.end(), val);

    return p != dest.end();
}
```

> Is the vector even neccessary?

No, it could be simplified as follows.

```
template<class T>
bool contains(const T *arr, int size, T val)
{
    const T* end = arr + size;
    return find(arr, end, val) != end;
}
```